# MDX - Visual totals on user hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

I'd like to have a visual total on a user hierarchy in MDX

That's to say :
I've got a team T1, 
with people P1,P2,P3.
Each of these people has got a yearly objective O1,O2,O3

at certain date in this year, only P2 has worked.
By filtering the people on a other measure called "Profit Potential".

I see

```
Team Hierachy | Objective
--------------+-------------
"T1 - (all)"  |  O1 + O2 +O3
"T1 - P2 "    |  O2
"T2 - (all)   |  O4
(snip)        | (snap)
```

Since P1 and P3 wind up not involved at all, what I want to achieve is

```
Team Hierachy | Objective
--------------+-------------
"T1 - (all)"  |  O2 
"T1 - P2 "    |  O2
"T2 - (all)   |  O4
(snip)        | (snap)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to enable visual totals :

First method is to use the MDX VisualTotals (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145527.aspx).

OR

The second method is to use a role and check the "Enable visual totals" checkbox (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/barbaro/archive/2008/02/06/visual-totals-in-mdx-and-role-security.aspx).

Since you do not want to apply security, you must go with the MDX approach.

Comment: I've already stumbled upon this function, and at first it did not seem to do the right. In fact it does.

Comment: When someone tells you that's the right function, you simply work until it works ;-)